# MPI_Abort and dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, mpi, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning to program in MPI in C and I didn't manage to find what happens with the dynamically allocated memory (malloc/calloc) in all processes from a MPI communicator/group when one of the processes calls MPI_Abort.

Not freeing the dynamically allocated memory can cause malfunctions/unpredictable behaviors? Is this considered as a leak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MPI_Abort()` is analogous to `exit()`:

> This routine makes a "best attempt" to abort all tasks in the group of
>   `comm`.  This function  does  not  require  that  the  invoking 
>   environment  take  any  action  with  the  error code.  However, a
>   Unix or POSIX environment should handle this as a return errorcode
>   from the main program.

([MPI 3.1 specification](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf))

Where it is effective at aborting processes, any dynamically-allocated memory held by those processes is released back to the OS.  Dynamic allocations do not survive process termination.  So,

> Not freeing the dynamically allocated memory can cause malfunctions/unpredictable behaviors?

To some extent.

> Is this considered as a leak?

There is no leak of `malloc()`ed or `calloc()`ed memory arising from the operation of `MPI_Abort()`.  Memory leaking is relevant only in the context of a process that continues to run.

Comment: I opted to delete, thanks for the option :)  Your answer more accurately addresses the issues.